# Change intel parallel Studio 2018 install directory

Tags: linux, intel, intel-parallel-studio

I am going crazy with the parallel studio installer. I installed some time ago PS2018.1 in a first directory. Now I would like to install PS2018.2 in another directory.

The installer tells me that I cannot install PS2018.2 in another directory because it has detected my previous installation of PS2018.1. So I uninstalled PS2018.1 with the uninstall_GUI.sh tool in the PS2018.1 install directory, and remove manually this (cleaned) install directory.

But when I try to install PS2018.2, the installer still says that I have a previous installation (which does not exists anymore...) and so do not let me install where I want.

My questions are:

- How does the installer detect this previous installation whereas I uninstalled it. There must be a file storing that information somewhere, but where?
- Is it possible to have multiple installations of PS at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems there is some metadata stored in

`/opt/intel`

so basically although i had specified a different install dir, `/opt/intel` was still created. So if you are sure you do not want the content of `/opt/intel` (such as the license info and you can re-activate it) just delete `/opt/intel`. That solved the problem for me at least.